# Today Was vs Today Is

Tags: tenses, time

If someone asks, "What day is it today?" and it is 10 pm, is it correct to respond with

> "Today **was** Tuesday."

since the day is over and it's night? Is that response incorrect? Should the correct response be

> "Today **is** Tuesday."?

Comment: General Reference. Today ***means*** "the current day", so if you're asking what day of the week it is, it can only be in present tense, since it's *still* that day for the whole 24 hours. In other contexts, it's okay to say, for example, *"Today **has been** a nice day"* nearer the end of the day, when the events that made it a nice day are finished (or at least, nearly so).

Answer (score 3):

Today **has been** a bitch! It's only 11 a.m. and things aren't going all that well. Restaurant employee problems. But it's still Wednesday here in Taiwan.

At 10 p.m., if I decide to go to sleep and not get up until tomorrow, then I'll say "Today **was** a bitch!" because the day will be over for me, even if you stay up till midnight. But it'll still be Wednesday here in Taiwan. So if you were to ask me  "What day is it today?" before I nodded off, I'd say "*It **is** still Wednesday, as far as I know*".

Tense is relative to events, not necessarily to the clock. And some theoretical physicists tell us that time isn't real anyway. Others say that it bends along with space, which still others allege is vacant. No wonder tense and the sequence of tenses are so confusing. Especially for everyone who lives in countless alternative universes.

I live in my own universe, a universe for one: Corvette.

Answer (score 2):

You could only say "Today *was* Tuesday" if it's midnight and Tuesday has passed into Wednesday.

"Day" can mean both "period of light" and "24-hour calendar slot". Which one depends on context. By asking "what day is today?", the implied context is more likely to be the second one, since 'what day' expects a calendar answer.

If someone instead said "Isn't it a lovely day?" as the sun is setting, then you could respond "It *was* a lovely day" since the implied context is more likely to be the period of light.

Comment: *Day* can indeed be restricted to the period of daylight, and 'today was' may be appropriate when referring to that period later in the same calendar day, but it can also be restricted to something like business hours, and 'today was' may be similarly appropriate when referring to that period later in the same calendar day.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: Today **is** Tuesday.

Incorrect: Today was Tuesday.

We can use the simple present with 'today'. We cannot use the simple past with 'today'.

We can also use the present perfect with 'today'. I have written a letter today. (Today is not finished.)

We can use both the present perfect and the simple past with 'this morning'. They have different meanings.

**Present** perfect- I have written a letter **this morning**. (It is still morning.)

Simple **past**- I wrote a letter **this morning**. (It is afternoon or evening.)

Comment: Perhaps ELL wasn't around when this question was asked, but it's far too basic for ELU. Adding answers is unhelpful as other basic questions are encouraged. // _And ELU welcomes answers to less basic questions **provided they are accompanied by supporting references**_.